# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory while using pysftp

Tags: python, python-2.7, pysftp

I am trying to do a script to find files that contain a text string. The files are on a remote host but when I run it, I get an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "dirsearch.py", line 55, in
>   
>       fo = open(search_path + fname) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/black/white/goto/reports/dbs-01-Apr-2017.log'

The script I used is below.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import absolute_import
from builtins import input
from builtins import open
from future import standard_library
standard_library.install_aliases()

import pysftp 

#connect to sftp server
srv = pysftp.Connection(host="host", username="username",
password="password")

#acess remote directory on server
search_path = ('/home/black/white/goto/reports/')

file_type = '.log'
search_str = input("Enter the search string : ")

#addition ........or fname in os.listdir(path=search_path):

for fname in srv.listdir(search_path):

   # Apply file type filter   
   if fname.endswith(file_type):

        # Open file for reading

        fo = open(search_path + fname)

        # Read the first line from the file
        line = fo.readline()

        # Initialize counter for line number
        line_no = 1

        # Loop until EOF
        while line != '' :
                # Search for string in line
                index = line.find(search_str)
                if ( index != -1) :
                    print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")

                # Read next line
                line = fo.readline()  

                # Increment line counter
                line_no += 1
        # Close the files
        fo.close()

srv.close()
```

Comment: Python's `open` looks for the file on your local machine. It looks like your script is finding filenames remotely, but then tries to open files with those same filenames from your local machine, which then don't exist.

You're missing the step of downloading the files before opening them.